# Why is this complaining about having an extra operand?

Tags: c, compare

I'm trying to compare my output to my instructor's output and he gave us this set of commands to follow, but for the second to last command, it complains about having an extra operand in 'output.diff'.

```
$ gcc -ansi -Wall -Werror -lm -o myprint-badges print-badges32.o grove.c badges.c

$./myprint-badges > my.out
$./print-badges32 > alex.out
$ diff my.out alex.out output.diff
$ more output.diff
```

Why won't the second to last command work?

Comment: You should have read the second line of diff's output: "diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to redirect the output (you missed the `>`):

```
diff my.out alex.out > output.diff
```

Instead of the above, you could have just piped it into `more`:

```
diff my.out alex.out | more
```

Comment: Why not `less`? (+1 though/of cause for giving additional information.)

Comment: Sure, `less` is fine.  But the original question uses `more`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to redirect the `diff` output:

```
diff my.out alex.out > output.diff
```

Answer (score 0):

Because "Diff" compares two files line by lines. You are giving three files to compares hence the error.

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff

I think correct command syntax would be

```
$ diff my.out alex.out >  output.diff
```

Comment: `>>` appends to a file. I don't think that that is appropriate in OP's case.

Comment: I don't think the OP is wanting to *append* results.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting getting similar error on windows when I run following command on GIT bash.

```
   diff -qrbB C:/Users/testuser/Desktop/Data bkp/files  C:/xampp/htdocs/Data/files
```

as there was a space in between Data and bkp as `Data bkp`

After removing this space it worked fine.

Other way is using a backslash

```
diff -qrbB C:/Users/testuser/Desktop/Data\ bkp/files  C:/xampp/htdocs/Data/files
```